# Vue.js - Global Data from AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

I'm giving [Vue.js](http://vuejs.org/) a try and so far I'm loving it because it's much simpler than angular. I'm currently using [vue-router](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router) and [vue-resource](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource) in my single page app, which connects to an API on the back end. I think I've got things mostly working with a the primary `app.js`, which loads vue-router and vue-resource, and several separate components for each route.

Here's my question: How do I use [props](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Passing_Data_with_Props) to pass global data to the child components when the data is fetched using an asynchronous AJAX call? For example, the list of users can be used in just about any child component, so I would like the primary `app.js` to fetch the list of users and then allow each child component to have access to that list of users. The reason I would like to have the `app.js` fetch the list of users is so I only have to make one AJAX call for the entire app. Is there something else I should be considering?

When I use the `props` in the child components right now, I only get the empty array that the `users` variable was initialized as, not the data that gets fetched after the AJAX call. Here is some sample code:

Simplified App.js

```
var Vue = require('vue');

var VueRouter = require('vue-router')
Vue.use(VueRouter);
var router = new VueRouter({
    // Options
});

router.map({
    '*': {
        component: {
            template: '<p>Not found!</p>'
        }
    },
    '/' : require('./components/dashboard.js'),
});

Vue.use(require('vue-resource'));

var App = Vue.extend({
    ready: function() {
        this.fetchUsers();
    },

    data: function() {
        return {
            users: [],
        };
    },

    methods: {
        fetchUsers: function() {
            this.$http.get('/api/v1/users/list', function(data, status, response) {
                this.users = data;
            }).error(function (data, status, request) {
                // handle error
            });
        }
    }
});

router.start(App, '#app')
```

Simplified app.html

```
<div id="app" v-cloak>
    <router-view users = "{{ users }}">
    </router-view>
</div>
```

Simplified dashboard.js

```
module.exports = {
    component: {
        ready: function() {
            console.log(this.users);
        },

        props: ['users'],
    },
};
```

When `dashboard.js` gets run, it prints an empty array to the console because that's what `app.js` initializes the `users` variable as. How can I allow `dashboard.js` to have access to the `users` variable from `app.js`? Thanks in advance for your help!

p.s. I don't want to use the `inherit: true` option because I don't want ALL the `app.js` variables to be made available in the child components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is actually working and you are being misled by the asynchronous behavior of `$http`. Because your `$http` call does not complete immediately, your `console.log` is executing before the `$http` call is complete.

Try putting a `watch` on the component against `users` and put a `console.log` in that handler.

Like this:

```
module.exports = {
    component: {
        ready: function() {
            console.log(this.users);
        },

        props: ['users'],

        watch: {
            users: {
                handler: function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    console.log("users is now", this.users);
                },
                deep: true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried what you said, and the "users is now..." never gets fired :-(

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console? And what version of Vue are you using?

Comment: No errors in the JS console. Vue.js v0.12.12, latest that's pulled in from npm.

Comment: Actually, David, you're my hero! There was a stupid mistake I made on my end. The answer you gave was right on!

Answer (score 3):

In the new version of Vue 1.0.0+ you can simply do the following, users inside your component is automatically updated:

```
<div id="app" v-cloak>
    <router-view :users="users"></router-view>
</div>
```